# Get the DEF property of a x3d node

Tags: python, file-format

Currently when Blender loads an .x3d file it does not load the [correct DEF attribute](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/X3D_shape_and_geometry#DEF_and_USE), i.e., each shape doesn't get its designated name, and instead is called `ShapeIndexedFaceSetXXX`.

Is there some way to fix this bug via Python scripting, or is it something deeper?

Comment: it is in python you can find it in ,`\scripts\addons\io_scene_x3d\import_x3d.py`

Comment: You should file a bug report olamundo: https://developer.blender.org/ , or, if you do fix it submit a bug patch.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Blender's source code.
These questions are considered outside the scope of this StackExchange as [defined in the help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Development questions should be asked of the developers directly instead, see the [contacting developers page of the blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem: In Blender 2.74, inside

```
def getDefName(self):
        data = self.x3dNode.getAttributeNode('DEF')
        if data:
            data.value  # XXX, return??
        return None
```

Does not return the name in case it found it, changing it to

```
def getDefName(self):
        data = self.x3dNode.getAttributeNode('DEF')
        if data:
            return data.value  # XXX, return??
        return None
```

worked for me, however I don't know how to suggest it as a bug fix nor am I sure that it is indeed a worthy fix as clearly someone already noticed that this function doesn't return anything in case there is a DEF.